# Resetting USB Driver

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a SOM module working on AM3352 TI processor. It has 2 USB ports. One of the port is connected to a USB hub on-to which a USB camera is connected.

AM3352 USB <---------- USB HUB <----------- USB Camera

On the system I also have another module which runs on 6.3 V. Since my input is only 5V, I am using a DC-DC converter to boost the voltage to 6.3.

What I observe is that, when I turn on the 6.3V module, there is dip in my input voltage for a short duration. The VBUS goes below 4.4V for this time period and I get a VBUS error. The voltage goes back to the previous state after this time but my device gets dropped. I wont be able to use the camera after this

Is there a way to restart the full usb driver so that the camera will get detected and I can use it for the intended purpose?

Comment: did you try `rmmod` and `insmod` combo ?

Comment: IIRC on something like a beagleboard you can actually control the power to the downstream USB port, not sure if that applies to you.  Or you may be able to restart the root hub.